# Mysql multi group and order is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to optimize a mysql query used for an eCommerce - custom shop, the query has a few inner joins and group by, count that make the query extremely slow, we are using it to generate dynamic  filters/combinations for categories, suppliers, colors, etc.

Anyone has any idea on how to optimize it? 
For one, i cannot manage to make the products(p) table to use a multiple index instead of the primary key, the query takes around 150-200ms.

The exact query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sl.id_supplier), 
       count(DISTINCT p.id_product) as product_count, 
       sl.supplier_name, 
       sl.supplier_slug, 
       sl.supplier_link 
FROM supplier s 
INNER JOIN supplier_lang sl 
  on s.id_supplier = sl.id_supplier 
  AND sl.id_project = 6 
  AND sl.id_lang =2 
  AND s.id_project = 6 
  AND s.active = 1 
INNER JOIN product p 
  ON p.id_project = 6 
  and p.active = 1 
  AND p.id_supplier = sl.id_supplier 
INNER JOIN product_category pc 
  on pc.id_project = 6 
  and pc.id_category = 6 
  and p.id_product = pc.id_product  
GROUP by sl.id_supplier 
ORDER BY sl.supplier_name ASC
```

Thank you

https://snag.gy/F6dy4r.jpg

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. Also, it's fairly safe to assume that you will never use it in conjunction with an aggregate function, except as per your second use.

Comment: And please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Also, it's odd that all the id_projects should be 6, and yet you choose not to relate the data on that fact.

Answer (score 1):

While there is an implicit functional dependency in the above, I think it's good practice (and would normally expect) that a query like that would look more like this:

```
SELECT sl.id_supplier
     , sl.supplier_name
     , sl.supplier_slug
     , sl.supplier_link 
     , COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_product) product_count 
  FROM supplier s 

  JOIN supplier_lang sl 
    ON sl.id_supplier = s.id_supplier 
   AND sl.id_project = s.id_project 
   AND sl.id_lang = 2 

  JOIN product p  
    ON p.id_supplier = sl.id_supplier 
   AND p.id_project = s.id_project  
   AND p.active = 1 

  JOIN product_category pc 
    ON pc.id_product = p.id_product 
   AND pc.id_project = p.id_project 
   AND pc.id_category = 6 

 WHERE s.id_project = 6 
   AND s.active = 1 

 GROUP 
    BY sl.id_supplier 
     , sl.supplier_name
     , sl.supplier_slug
     , sl.supplier_link 
 ORDER 
    BY sl.supplier_name ASC
```

For help with optimizing this query we would need to see SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables as well as the EXPLAIN for the above. This would be in the form of an EDIT to your question, and would not include any pictures.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will try this version to see if it's faster, also there is a table print screen and explain link  in the original post: https://snag.gy/F6dy4r.jpg

Comment: @PepeleaRazvanIonut It won't be faster. Unfortunately, I don't do pictures of text. And besides, an EXPLAIN is fairly meaningless without sight of the available indexes.

Comment: the reason i have put a picture is that next to it, its the entire database structure and indexes, i thought that was the easiest way for anyone to help and understand.

Comment: It's fine that you thought that. But you're mistaken. What we like is text.